# Publishing 5 messages per second to PubSub Topic, Pull Subscription Backlog with No Worker Is Not Growing

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

I'm trying to tune how many workers I need on a pull subscription from a PubSub topic getting about 5 messages per second. When I turn off all the workers, I expect to see the backlog bytes start to grow - no work is being done. However, I'm not seeing that, instead, the backlog bytes sits at zero and unack'd messages sits at zero. Is that expected?

Answer (score 0):

I had a misconfiguration where another worker was pulling from this subscription - the answer is yes, with both push and pull subscriptions the expectation is that undelivered bytes goes up with no workers.